# Comma-delimited properties to actual properties with Underscore or Lo-Dash

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

If I have something like

```
var obj = [{keywords: "a, b, c"}, {keywords: "d, e, f"}]
```

and do

```
var result = _.pluck(obj, 'keywords')
```

I get

```
result == ['a, b, c', 'd, e, f']
```

I'd like to have

```
result == ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

is there any simple, short way to accomplish that with underscore or lo-dash? Without iterating over result, doing a string split and putting that into a new array?

Comment: Then do `result = result.map(function (d) { return d.split(", ");})` afterwards, which you can then flatten.

Comment: @royhowie That will return `[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]`. He needs to append them afterward.

Comment: @Barmar hence why I said "which you can then flatten"—he can just chain `.flatten()` to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Without iterating over result, doing a string split and putting that into a new array"?

No; any solution will wind up doing some version of that. You can, however, express that iteration/split/array construction fairly concisely:

```
_.flatten(_.map(obj, function(o){ return o.keywords.split(/,\s*/) }))
```

or if you prefer method-chaining:

```
_.chain(_.map(obj, function(o){ return o.keywords.split(/,\s*/) })).flatten()
```

but in that case, you might prefer this even more:

```
_(obj).map(function(o){ return o.keywords.split(/,\s*/) })).flatten()
```

(This is one of the cases that makes me wish Underscore/LoDash had a `flatMap`; calling `flatten` on the result of a regular `map` destroys any deep structure.)

Comment: Thanks :) I'm happy with `_.flatten(_.map(obj, function(o){ return o.keywords.split(/, /) }));`

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
var result = _(obj).pluck('keywords').join().replace(/\s/g, '').split(',');
```

---

Edit: A shorter version, ramifications discussed in the comments:

```
var result = _(obj).pluck('keywords').join().split(/[\s,]+/);
```

Comment: Nice. But couldn't you split on `/[,\s]+/` and avoid the `replace`?

Comment: I guess you could. Didn't think of that, makes it even shorter.

Comment: I would split on `/,\s*/` just to avoid treating multiple commas as a single delimiter, not that the situation arises here.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that you're taking advantage of the fact that `join` defaults to `join(',')`.  So it just happens to insert *between* the strings the same delimiter that is already present *in* the strings.  Otherwise, you'd wind up with `['a','b','cd','e','f']` or similar.

Comment: There you go, it was correct before we tried to be clever about it.

Answer (score 2):

Without underscore:

```
[].concat.apply([], obj.map(function(o) { return o.keywords.split(/[,\s]+/); }))
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `concat` does a kind of flattening, in the sense that it adds individual elements in arrays in the argument list to the result.